# How to split by space and dot in java

Tags: java, string

I have many text like '**J.Depp** is an American actor.'
How can i split where **J.Depp** like  "**J.** Depp"
I write some code but it doesn't work

```
list.forEach(it -> {
        String[] s = it.split(" ");
        for (String temp : s) {
            if (temp.contains(".")) {
                String[] temp2 = temp.split(".");
               // 
            }
        }
        list2.add(s + " .");
    });
```

Comment: What you want to do? Add whitespace after dot?

Comment: yeah, i want to add whitespace after dot

Comment: Use replace, something like '"j.depp".replace(".", ". ")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replaceAll()` will do the trick

```
temp.replaceAll("\\.", ". ");
```

To skip dots which already have the whitespace you may use non-capturing negative lookahead:

```
temp.replaceAll("\\.(?!\\s)", ". ");
```

See also `Pattern` reference.

Answer (score 1):

split takes a regexp, and . has special meaning. I suggest:

```
temp.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

This way you can split on whatever you want. (Just `temp.split("\\.")` would also work, but the pattern quote variant is more readable and works for anything you care to split on, hence why you should write it that way.